# Android - Ormlite query for searching a string

Tags: android, ormlite

I am working on an app, in that I want to search a string which matches with the string in the table, I have written following code,

```
public ArrayList<LearningListDTO> getSearchLearningList(String searchString) {

    ArrayList<LearningListDTO> learningListDTO = null;
    QueryBuilder<LearningListDTO, Integer> contentByTypeQB = null;
    PreparedQuery<LearningListDTO> preparedQuery = null;

    try {

        contentByTypeQB = getLearningDao().queryBuilder();
        contentByTypeQB.orderByRaw("name ASC");
        contentByTypeQB.where().like("name", "%" + searchString + "%");

        Log.v("",
                "Query Executed: "
                        + contentByTypeQB.prepareStatementString());

        preparedQuery = contentByTypeQB.prepare();

        try {
            learningListDTO = (ArrayList<LearningListDTO>) getLearningDao().query(
                    preparedQuery);
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return learningListDTO;
}
```

Actually I want a query something like, "If I type B then it should first display the strings starting with B then strings which contains 'B'(though it is starting with A)"

Is it a way for this?

Thanks in advance. :)